# Java Grid Class

Tags: java, class, grid

I am trying to make a java grid w/ the intended output as:
[image]

but my output is off by one as in it looks like this: 
[image]
. Any Suggestions?

```
public class Grid {

    private int rows = 0;
    private int columns = 0;
    private String [] [] grid; 
    public Grid(int rows, int columns){
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
        grid = new String [rows] [columns];
        initializeGrid();
    }

    public void initializeGrid(){
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                grid [i] [j] = "| ";
            }
        }
    }

    public void printGrid(){
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
            System.out.println("|");
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j){
                System.out.print(grid[i][j] + "      ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you call `printGrid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Looks like you should have this method like this 

 public void printGrid(){
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j){
                System.out.print(grid[i][j] + "      ");
            }
               System.out.println("|");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Matthias!

Comment: no problem can u please mark my solution as solved would be nice best greetings :)